# What options does a person have for showing evidence in favour of the null hypothesis?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, mixed-model, prior

I have a linear mixed-effects model with a theoretically important null result. Of course a reviewer asked for a Bayesian approach to "show evidence" for it.

However I am struggling with Bayes Factors because of their dependence on a prior, and in this case, my best bet seems to just be trying it with a range of default priors. I don't find this very convincing.

I wonder if there are other, better, options?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/equivalence/info

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I don't have enough context to give a full answer, but I'll try. Depending on your model you could consider a diffuse prior. You could also check literature on similar models and base your choice of prior thereon.

I don't understand what you mean by theoretically important. As in, not rejected? If you mean that you are interested in H0 is true, can't you reformulate to switch H0 and Ha?

Comment: Thanks! A few follow up questions. 1) What do you mean by reformulating to switch H0 and Ha? 2) I've seen a few default priors recommended: cauchy(0,1), normal(0, 2.5). Are there others that you'd suggest?

Comment: I would guess those defaults are suggested because they are unspecific. A diffuse prior bears no information, they are basically a hack to get rid of the prior altogether. Could you still explain what you mean by theoretically important H0?

Comment: Well it is an effect that I think many in the field would expect to exist, and its nonexistence has implications for how this particular phenomenon operates.

Comment: Then your H0 should be that it exists right? So you want to collect evidence against that H0? Wouldn't the normal road of testing if you can reject H0 then work?